# MapBasic, MapInfo Pro automation of existing Raster Operations

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I have the latest version of MapInfo Pro and I would like to know if it is possible to fully automate the use of existing Raster operations into several files at once?

For example, having several hundred raster files such as .grd with a specific coordinate system, I would like to create a batch file that would call on the "Reproject" feature available in the raster operation to execute that feature on hundreds of files instead of me doing it manually for each .grd file.

Is it possible to do so, and is it possible to do it on any Raster operation available in MapInfo Pro?

Comment: If you have the MapBasic window open, MapInfo will list what command(s) corresponds to what you're doing. Do your actions show up there? If yes, you just have to get the list of files from somewhere and write a loop.

Comment: The MapBasic window doesn't capture the statements from MapInfo Pro Raster

Answer (score 1):

The raster capabilities of MapInfo Pro, and MapInfo Pro Advanced, can be automated using the MapInfo Raster SDK. This is a .NET based SDK so it's not possible to use built-in MapBasic statements to run raster operations.

You would have to write either a MapBasic application that uses the .NET methods from the MapInfo Raster SDK, or write a .NET utility that uses the .NET ask.

The latter would probably be easiest. But that does require some skills in .NET programming.

Another option is to use the interface in MapInfo Pro to batch process your files.

Check the *Batch Mode* option and you can select multiple input files in the *Convert window*.
[image]